# I'm trying to fix a "filter chain halted" error in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The error message I am receiving states:

```
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_request rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
```

I am attempting to access a page called `localhost:3000/items`

I've gotten rid of the `before_action` completely and got it to run, but I need the authentication to work.

**EDIT**
I'm receiving a token by doing the following in terminal:

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"email":"example@mail.com","password":"123123123"}' http://localhost:3000/authenticate
```

When I receive the token, I then try to pass it with the following:

```
$ curl -H "Authorization: 123EXAMPLETOKEN123" http://localhost:3000/items
```

Here is my application_controller which I believe is the main source of my trouble

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
 before_action :authenticate_request
 attr_reader :current_user

 private

 def authenticate_request
  @current_user = AuthorizeApiRequest.call(request.headers).result
  render json: { error: 'Not Authorized' }, status: 401 unless @current_user
 end
end
```

The following code, which I believe could also be related to the issue, my `AuthorizeApiRequest`

```
class AuthorizeApiRequest
 prepend SimpleCommand

 def initialize(headers = {})
  @headers = headers
 end

 def call
  user
 end

 private

 attr_reader :headers

 def user
  @user ||= User.find(decoded_auth_token[:user_id]) if decoded_auth_token
  @user || errors.add(:token, 'Invalid token') && nil
 end

 def decoded_auth_token
  @decoded_auth_token ||= JsonWebToken.decode(http_auth_header)
 end

 def http_auth_header
  if headers['Authorization'].present?
   return headers['Authorization'].split(' ').last
  else
   errors.add(:token, 'Missing token')
  end
  nil
 end
end
```

Comment: It looks like you need to send a valid JsonWebToken in your request header.

Comment: What are the headers being passed along with your request?

Comment: @TheGeorgeous: I thought 'Authorization' was being passed. I'm using a token based authentication.

I'm then using that token in the following:
**$ curl -H "Authorization: TOKEN" http://localhost:3000/items**

Comment: @eikes: I'm receiving a token by doing the following in Terminal:
**$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"email":"example@mail.com","password":"123123123"}' http://localhost:3000/authenticate**

and then sending that token in the following:
**$ curl -H "Authorization: TOKEN" localhost:3000/items**

Comment: @howthegodschill, it will help if you log the headers you are receiving in this bit of code and post it here. Even if you passed it, headers might get being tampered with before you receive it in the class